# Get the numbers after ":" and count them with the help of powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text, count

Could someone please help me with extracting and counting the numbers from a text file with PowerShell?

Example: `c:\temp\1.txt` is some text with semicolon and numbers after them. I need to sum all of these numbers.

```
blablabl:5 dzfdsfdsfsdfsf:10
sdfsdfsdfdffs:8sdfsfsfdsfdsf:111
```

5+10+8+111...

What I've tried so far:

```bsh
$LogText = "C:\temp\1.txt"
[regex]$Regex = "\. (\d+):[1]"
$Matches = $Regex.Matches($LogText)
$Matches | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host  $Matches
}
#$array = @()
#$array = new-object collections.arraylist
$array = while ($Matches.Success) {
  Write-Host $array[i++]
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

$text = Get-Content "C:\temp\1.txt"
[regex]$Regex = "\d"
$Matches = $Regex.Matches($text)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

$pos = $text.IndexOf(":")
$rightPart = $text.Substring($pos+1)
Write-Host $rightPart
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) to extract the matches from the file and [`Measure-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) to do the calculation.

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\temp\1.txt' -Pattern '(?<=:)\d+' -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value |
    Measure-Object -Sum |
    Select-Object -Expand Sum
```

`(?<=:)` is a positive lookbehind assertion to match the colon preceding the number without making it part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
$txt= 
@"
blablabl:5 dzfdsfdsfsdfsf:10
sdfsdfsdfdffs:8sdfsfsfdsfdsf:111
"@
[regex]$Regex = '\d+'

$sum=0;
$Regex.Matches($txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $val = [int]$_.Value
    $val
    $sum+=$val
}
$sum
```

Comment: I modified it a bit, however it doesn't gave me an sum of one number
$txt= get-content "C:\temp\1.txt"
[regex]$Regex = '\d+'
$Matches =@(($Regex.Matches($text)))
$sum=0;
$Regex.Matches($txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $val = [int]$_.Value
    $val
    $sum+=$val
}
$sum
2
1
123456789
12345
98
7
3
141
6180
9
0
42
555
123
4567
1
800
555
2468
52415
50
50
40
123537241